# mysql query string field with int, returns equivalent of ('int-%')

Tags: mysql

This is kind of a weird quirk I noticed and I really just wanted to see if someone could provide insight as to why its happening.

Lets say we have a field called "account" that's a varchar(x)

These two queries will return the same result set.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE account = 1234;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE account LIKE '1234%';
```

I stumbled on this by accident in a script I wrote to migrate some older data and I accidentally forgot to encapsulate my string.

Can anyone tell me why this behavior happens?

---

update:

I feel like I may have no explained this well enough so I'm going to provide a sample table:

table_name:
id - INT
account - varChar(50)

entries:

```
ID - account
1 - "1"
2 - "12"
3 - "123"
4 - "1234"
```

so:

**1:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE account LIKE '1%'
```

will return entries 1, 2, 3, 4

**2:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE account = 1
```

will return entries 1, 2, 3, 4

**3:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE account = '1'
```

will return entry 1

Why is 1 the same as 2, and why is 2 not the same as 3

Answer (score 3):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html

"...MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa."

Comment: I understand that mysql does automatic conversions, what I'm more interested in is the LIKE statement that seems to become implied.

Comment: Could we clarify this a little? 1) What behavior did you expect? 2) How was it different from what you observed?

Comment: I see, after your edit. Looks like you are right. It's indeed implies LIKE, similarly to Perl & Co. Simplifying, the answer is, "Because it's MySQL." ;) It used to be strange but evolved into a decent product. Seriously, I think that behavior is wrong and would submit a bug report.

Comment: Honestly that's what I expected to hear I just wanted to make sure I wasn't interpreting something wrong or just misunderstood how MYSQL interprets these types of conversions.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

This is because % is a meta character which means any number of characters including zero characters. `Like` keyword looks for the pattern which begins with 1234.
Since account = 1234 which also matches the criteria, you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think at this point this has been discovered as a MYSQL bug, I filed a bug report id #67427 if anyone is interested in getting an update I would direct you to view it through http://bugs.mysql.com/